# Prove the root is less than $2^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, proof-writing, contest-math

> A polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ such that coefficient of $x^k$ is $a_k$. Another constructed polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n$ is present such that the coefficeint of $x^k$ is $\frac{a_k}{2^k-1}$. If $1$ and $2^{n+1}$ are roots of $g(x)$, show that $f(x)$ has a positive root less than $2^n$.

Personally a tough problem. **Hints Only Please!**

I got that: $f(x) = g(2x) - g(x)$

Also,

$f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^k$ and $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k x^k}{2^k - 1}$ and $h(x) = g(2x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k a_k x^k}{2^k - 1}$

$g(1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{2^k - 1} = 0$

$g(2^{n+1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k a_k 2^{nk}}{2^k - 1} = 0$

Realize that: $g(2^{n + 1}) = g(2 \cdot 2^{n}) = h(2^n). $ Hence the root of $h(x) = g(2x) \implies x =  2^n$.

Since $h(1/2) = g(1) = 0$, it follows $x= \frac{1}{2}$ is a root for $h(x) = g(2x)$.

So I have:

$g(x) = 0 \implies x = \{1, 2^{n+1} \}$

$g(2x) = 0 \implies x = \{\frac{1}{2}, 2^{n}\}$.

Now suppose $x = 2^{n} + i$. Then,

$g(2x) = g(2^{n+1} + 2i) > g(2^{n+1}) = 0$.

$g(x) = g(2^n + i)$

But I'm not sure what to do next?

Comment: How does the problem statement handle the constant term of $g$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you meant that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g(x)$ is $\frac{a_k}{2^k-1}$ for each $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ and that the constant term of $f(x)$ is $0$.  If $f$ has no root in the interval $\left(1,2^{n}\right)$, then either it is strictly positive or strictly negative on this interval.  Without loss of generality, assume that $f$ is strictly positive on $\left(1,2^n\right)$.  Show that $g\left(2^{n+1}\right)>0$, which contradicts the condition that $g\left(2^{n+1}\right)=0$.  Hence, $f$ must have a root in the interval $\left(1,2^n\right)$.

If the constant term of $f$ may be nonzero, then this problem is false.  A counterexample is given by $f(x)=3x^2-5x+3$ and $g(x)=x^2-5x+4$.

Comment: (+1) but how to show $g(2^{n+1}) > 0$?

Comment: Hint: $g\left(2^{n+1}\right) = \sum_{r=0}^n\, \Big(g\left(2^{r+1}\right)-g\left(2^r\right)\Big)+g(1)$.

Comment: $g(2x) - g(x) = F(x)$. $g(1) = 0, g(2^{n+1}) = 0$. Goal is $(0, 2^n)$.$F(2^n) =  g(2^{n+1}) - g(2^n) \implies F(2^n) = -g(2^n)$. Suppose since $(1, 2^{n+1})$ is monotonic, suppose $g(x) < 0$ so $g(2^n) < 0$ then $F(2^n) > 0$. $g(1) = 0$ and $g(1 \to 2^{n+1}) < 0$. Consider $a \in (1, 2^n)$. Consider the interval $(a/2, a)$ both greater than $1$. Since $g(x) < 0$ suppose there is a steady decrease in $(a/2, a)$ such that: $g(a) < g(a/2) \implies g(a) - g(a/2) < 0 \implies F(a/2) < 0$, since $0 < 1 < a/2  < 2^n < 2^{n+1}$ it follows by IVT, $F(x) = 0, x \in (a/2, 2^n)$.

Comment: **Question:** Like I assumed in $(a/2, a)$ that $g"(x) < 0, g'(x) < 0$ continuously.  Are we actually allowed to assume this?

Comment: I don't understand your attempt at solution.  Why do you have $g(x)<0$?  I never made any assumption on $g$.  Can you explain what you are doing more cleanly?

Comment: Ok, that is because we assumed that it is strictly negative during that interval

Comment: @Amad27.  Why did you assume that?  If you add additional assumptions, then you will not know which assumption of the two (i.e., $f$ has no roots in $\left(1,2^n\right)$ or $g(x)<0$) is leading to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: *This is just a wordy hint... :*

Assuming $a_0=0$, notice that $g(2x)$ is a horizontally scaled version of $g(x)$, which means that both functions have the same sign in $(\dfrac 12,2^n)$ and $(1,2^{n+1})$ respectively, so they have the same sign in $(1,2^n)$. On the left-most side of the interval, around $x=1$ (the root of $g(x)$), one function ***must*** be "*higher* than" the other, so that $g(2x)-g(x)>0$ or $g(2x)-g(x)<0$. Conversely, on the right-most side, around $x=2^n$, the inverse is true. Hence the difference, in either case, changes sign somewhere in the interval $(1,2^n)$ which means that...